# The mysterious case of the slow ethernet connection on a Debian router

Tags: debian, ethernet

I have adapted an Intel NUC to act as my home router. It handles a VLAN on the LAN for the wifi clients and some ethernet clients, the local LAN, an OpenVPN server, the WAN connection. The strange thing is that its WAN connection is **very** slow, about 2-3 Mb/s, when the outer line is 100Mb/s. Also, *ping* is similarly slowed down: pinging Google DNS goes from *3ms* *to 120ms*, and so on.

I have tried the obvious things:

1. Since the WAN connection is thru an USB-Ethernet adapter, I have recompiled and re-installed the newest version of the driver, *AX88179_178A*;
2. Changed the Ethernet cable **and** the USB-Ethernet adapter;
3. tested the ethernet port of the modem by plugging in my laptop;
4. tested the would-be router by using it as a normal LAN pc, and speed-testing all of its interfaces (they all work fine), with the same/different cables/adapters; in this case I **always** get speeds of 100Mb/s.

I have now come to believe I am dealing with some sort of bug, instead of a misconfiguration: in fact, this configuration has been **cloned** (*cat /dev/sda > /dev/sdb*) from a different headless server (an Asus Vivo PC), which I also use as a router, elsewhere, and on the Asus the configuration works flawlessly. But I am at a loss as to where to turn.

A hint comes from the fact that *ifconfig* does not detect packets passing thru:

```
# ifconfig eth2
eth2: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.239  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::223:54ff:fe6c:7527  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:23:54:6c:75:27  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 1  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

while *ip route* only displays this mysterious *noprefixroute* on the IPv4 line which puzzles me, since I thought this was an option of *IPv6* only:

```
# ip addr show eth2
3: eth2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:23:54:6c:75:27 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.239/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute eth2
       valid_lft 86150sec preferred_lft 86150sec
    inet6 fe80::223:54ff:fe6c:7527/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

The output above was produced after obtaining a DHCP address, normally I use static addresses, see below: it makes no difference whatsoever.

Relevant pieces of information: my */etc/network/interfaces*:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth2 
iface eth2 inet static
        address 192.168.1.128
        network 192.168.1.0
        gateway 192.168.1.254
        netmask 255.255.255.0

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static 
        address 192.168.73.1
        network 192.168.73.0
        netmask 255.255.255.0

iface eth0.10 inet manual
    vlan-raw-device eth0

iface brwifi inet static
        address 10.0.73.1
        network 10.0.73.0
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        bridge_ports eth0.10
        bridge_stp on
        pre-up sleep 3
        bridge_maxwait 10
```

the output of *ethtool* for the ailing interface, *eth2*:

```
ethtool eth2
Settings for eth2:
        Supported ports: [ TP MII ]
        Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                                1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full 
        Supported pause frame use: No
        Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
        Supported FEC modes: Not reported
        Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                                1000baseT/Full 
        Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric
        Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
        Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
        Link partner advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                                             100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                                             1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full 
        Link partner advertised pause frame use: No
        Link partner advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
        Link partner advertised FEC modes: Not reported
        Speed: 1000Mb/s
        Duplex: Full
        Port: MII
        PHYAD: 3
        Transceiver: internal
        Auto-negotiation: on
        Supports Wake-on: pg
        Wake-on: g
        Current message level: 0x00000007 (7)
                               drv probe link
        Link detected: yes
```

and the relevant part of the kernel ring buffer:

```
[   11.819082] ax88179_178a 2-1:1.0 eth2: renamed from eth1
[   11.864685] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth2: link is not ready
[   15.968067] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth2: link is not ready
[   19.608009] ax88179_178a 2-1:1.0 eth2: ax88179_178a - Link status is: 1
[   19.816004] ax88179_178a 2-1:1.0 eth2: ax88179_178a - Link status is: 1
[   19.919997] ax88179_178a 2-1:1.0 eth2: ax88179_178a - Link status is: 1
[   19.920021] ax88179_178a 2-1:1.0 eth2: Write medium type: 0x0033
[   20.023986] ax88179_178a 2-1:1.0 eth2: ax88179_178a - Link status is: 1
[   20.127989] ax88179_178a 2-1:1.0 eth2: ax88179_178a - Link status is: 1
[   20.335991] ax88179_178a 2-1:1.0 eth2: ax88179_178a - Link status is: 1
[   20.336093] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth2: link becomes ready
[   20.648006] ax88179_178a 2-1:1.0 eth2: link up, 1000Mbps, full-duplex, lpa 0xC3E1
[   20.965805] ax88179_178a 2-1:1.0 eth2: Write medium type: 0x0033
[   21.687979] ax88179_178a 2-1:1.0 eth2: link up, 1000Mbps, full-duplex, lpa 0xC3E1
```

For what it´s worth, I run a perfectly updated *Debian buster/sid*, and a suitable comment is: serves me right for not sticking to *stable*. But regardless, can anyone help, **please**?

Comment: It sounds like we can concentrate, on the difference between 1) WAN performance obtained by local processes on the NUC, 2) WAN performance obtained by a laptop wired directly to the NUC, 3) performance obtained for direct connections between the laptop and the NUC.  Perhaps you could set up this configuration and document the `ping` results for *all three* cases.  Testing bandwidth consistently for each case is more of a pain... I might try using a http download of a Linux ISO with `time curl -O http://...`. You can control the size of the download in curl using the `-r` option.

Comment: to test the bandwidth of case 3, you would first install a HTTP server on the router.

Comment: Not being able to count the bandwidth with `ifconfig eth2` (the USB ethernet WAN interface) seems real freaky though, I don't understand that.

Comment: The absence of counters is a good clue either the driver is badly coded or is for another version of the kernel ; that particular Ethernet chip set is known for being troublesome ; on top of it you have managed to compare two equipments without telling us what USB version they support. USB transmissions usually also tax CPU a lot, and USB is not well suitable for sustained speeds. All in all bad combinations.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Thanks for your comment, I downloaded the driver from the official ASIX site, http://www.asix.com.tw/products.php?op=pItemdetail&PItemID=131;71;112, which explicitly states it is suitable for Linux kernels 4.x, and I run a 4.16. As for the USB, it's 3.0 all over: the ports in use on both boxes, and for the driver as well. So I guess this leaves me the task of trying to debug the driver, right? Not exactly something I look forward to, I will have to come up with a different solution, I guess.

Comment: A colleague of mine bought a similar adapter from China, the driver was so badly botched that even told us a cable was connected when it was not. He gave up on trying to use it.  The site telling you the driver is for kernel 4 does not mean they did a good job porting it to 4.x. I bet they did not.